# SQL Count the numbers in a returned query?

Tags: sql, count, group-by, subquery, distinct

I have a query to retrieve the email addresses and the names (sometimes more than 1) associated with the email address, where the account status is not closed, in descending order:

```
SELECT sbg.contact_email, COUNT(DISTINCT sbg.contact_name) Num_Contact_Names
    FROM SummaryBillGroup sbg
    INNER JOIN Account a
        ON sbg.Customer_number = a.Customer_number
WHERE a.account_status_code <> 'c'
GROUP BY sbg.contact_email
ORDER BY Num_Contact_Names DESC
```

This returns a list of the email addresses and the number of names associated with each email address. What I would like to do now is use that query to count up all of the returned numbers, so that I have a list of the 3's, the 2's, the 1's, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use that same query as a derived table for another one. Like this:

```
    select num_contact_names, count(*)
from (SELECT sbg.contact_email, COUNT(DISTINCT sbg.contact_name) Num_Contact_Names
    FROM SummaryBillGroup sbg
    INNER JOIN Account a
        ON sbg.Customer_number = a.Customer_number
WHERE a.account_status_code  'c'
GROUP BY sbg.contact_email) as t
group by t.num_contact_names
order by 2
```

First row would give you 1's, second row the 2's and so on. Cheers.

Comment: Just needed a <> between the a.account_status_code  and the  'c'. Otherwise, perfect!